# Looking for a topic on differentiable manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I just finished a course on differentiable manifolds covering: 
Definition of differentiable manifold.

Tangent space.
Submanifold.
Partitions of unity.
Vector fields.

And I looking for a topic for a half an hour presentation (with the knowledge I have so far ) on manifolds.
The half hour restriction is the real problem here, because all the topics I find can’t be presented in such sort time.
An example of a topic ( which is unfortunately taken is the exponential map ).
Any ideas?
( I have to present a topic to show my professor I have a good understanding of the courses material)

P.S \
is an introduction to complex manifolds possible in this time period?

Comment: There is too much notation and technical baggage to get anywhere in a half hour discussing complex manifolds. Did you talk about Lie brackets and flows of vector fields? My favorite exercise to assign is the application of Lie brackets to parking cars. See, for example, [this handout](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/Math600F19/parking_a_car.pdf) or [this handout](https://ucb-ee106.github.io/106b-sp20site/assets/scribes/eecs106b_lecture8.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much, these seem very interesting topics, where i can find similar ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go on to talk about covector fields then general tensor fields both in local coordinates or in an invariant fashion. I recommend at least doing the local coordinates approach to get a "hands on" feel for the subject. You could then define the Riemannian metric tensor as a special $(0,2)$-tensor. If you still have time, you can also define the Levi-Civita connection, Lie bracket of vector fields, and even define the Riemann curvature tensor.

Depending on your speed, a subset of the above should constitute a great 30-minute talk.